# What is the confidence interval at 95% of VIP (Variable Importance for the Projection) in XLSTAT for Partial Least Squares Regression PLSR?

Tags: confidence-interval, xlstat

One of the outputs of XLSTAT for Partial Least Squares Regression PLSR is a plot showing VIP (Variable Importance for the Projection) and, as I understand, the confidence interval at 95% of each VIP under the form of black vertical lines for each variable, as shown in the figure below coming from https://help.xlstat.com/fr/6636-regression-pls-moindres-carrees-partiels-dans-excel.

- Could someone explain me how to interpret this confidence interval?
- What does it mean?
- Where does it come from?

[image]